# Alsa is not on Path and is not detecting soundcard 16.04 LTS

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, soundcard

I had a problem before where Ubuntu didn't detect my headphones which still is not fixed.

The problem now is that when i type `alsamixer` into terminal I get `cannot open mixer: No such file or directory` and when i type `aplay -l` I get `aplay: device_list:268: no soundcards found...`.

Ubuntu does find my soundcard when i type `lspci -v | grep -i audio`, it returns following:

```
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GM204 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
    Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation GM204 High Definition Audio Controller
```

Also `cat /proc/asound/cards` gives `cat: /proc/asound/cards: No such file or directory`

I have tried to reinstalling alsa-base, alsa-utils and linux-sound-base, and also tried

```
sudo aptitude --purge reinstall linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils linux-image-`uname -r` linux-ubuntu-modules-`uname -r` libasound2
```

with no success.

The sound settings show a "Dummy output" as speaker.

```
sudo lspci -vnn | awk -vRS= '/Audio device/'
```

Generates this:

```
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller [8086:8c20] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller [1043:12ff]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 3
    Memory at ed410000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GM204 High Definition Audio Controller [10de:0fbb] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation GM204 High Definition Audio Controller [10de:0fbb]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 10
    Memory at ed080000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [78] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
```

Comment: A more verbose `lspci` output (including kernel module information) such as `sudo lspci -vnn | awk -vRS= '/Audio device/'` might be helpful

Comment: As root, run `rmmod snd-hda-intel; modprobe snd-hda-intel`. Are there any new messages in the system log?

Comment: try booting with live usb and see if sound is working ok. if sound is working there it is something you changed after installing. if still no sound it could be hardware problem.